# socket io node js 404 (Not Found)

Tags: javascript, node.js, sockets

this is my server code

```
var http       = require('http');}
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var server = http.createServer(app);


 var io = require('socket.io').listen(server);

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
 .......................
});
server.listen(3000);
```

and my client code

```
<script src="http://192.168.0.106:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

user first one and used the second same think 404 not found

```
<script src="http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
```

when i open this link its show me socket.io code

> http://localhost:3000/socket.io/socket.io.js

but in console i see it get data from

> GET http://localhost/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1465217005494-2 404 (Not Found)

NOTE ** I am use popup window for this code

Comment: Can you add the client-side code you use to initiate a connection to the server?

Comment: @BenFortune i dont notice that there are second connect with    socket = io(); only this make my problem thanks man :)